# Exponential family distribution in terms of natural logarithm

Tags: probability, integration, proof-verification, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

I am studying a note on basic probability which introduced the exponential family as

$\left\{p(x;\theta): \theta \in \Theta\right\}$  where

$p(x;\theta) =h(x)c(\theta) \exp\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{k}w_{i}(\theta)t_i(x)\right\}$

The exponential family is rewritten in terms of a natural logarithm for k=1 as follows:

$p(x;\theta) =h(x)\exp\left\{ \eta t(x) - A(\eta)\right\}$ where
$A(\eta) = log\int h(x) exp\left\{ \eta t(x)\right\}dx$

Now, let assume $X$ have an exponential family distribution Then:

$E(t(X)) = A^{\prime}(\eta)$

$Var(t(X)) = A^{\prime\prime}(\eta)$

I am trying to prove the 2 expressions shown above.

===

First what is the role of t(X) in this expression? It just assumed X have an exponential family distribution.

and I don't really know how I can derive the above expression:
so far I just find the $ A^{\prime}(\eta)= \frac{d}{d\eta}log_b\int h(x)\exp \{\eta t(x)\}dx = log_b{e}\frac{\int h(x)t(x) \exp\left\{ \eta t(x)\right\}dx}{\int h(x)\exp\left\{ \eta t(x)\right\}dx}$

Can anyone help how to approach this problem please?

Thanks in advance.

=====

Assuming the base of $\log$ function is $e$, I proved $E(t(X))$ in the following way. I am not sure if it is right:

$E(t(X)) = \int (h(x)\exp\{\eta t(x) - A( \eta )\}t(x)dx$

$E(t(X)) = \int h(x)\frac{e^{\eta t(x) }} {e^{ A( \eta )}}t(x)dx$

$E(t(X)) = \frac{1}{e^{ A( \eta )}} \int h(x)e^{\eta t(x) }t(x)dx$

$E(t(X)) = \frac{ \int t(x)h(x)e^{\eta t(x) }dx}{ \exp\{log\int h(x) exp\left\{ \eta t(x)\right\}dx\}}$

$E(t(X)) = \frac{ \int t(x)h(x)e^{\eta t(x) }dx}{\int h(x) e^{\eta t(x) }dx}$

Comment: Start with $1=\int_{\Bbb R} h(x)\exp\{\eta t(x)-A(\eta)\}\,dx$, then differentiate with respect to $\eta$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I followed your hint. In the middle of proof I assumed  $e^{-A(\eta)}$ is a constant when we are integrating with respect to $x$. I just want to make sure if this is a right approach. I appreciate any insights you can provide.

Comment: I got it, it is straight forward now, Thanks again.